# Xocde canvas crashes

Tags: xcode, canvas, swiftui

I am creating and running a simple hello world app in Xcode 11.3.1. When I try to preview it in canvas the build succeeded and the canvas collapses. I am using Catalina version 10.15.3. The same issue is shown in Xcode 11.4 beta 3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, choosing **Show Current Editor** in **Focused Editor** solves the problem.

[image: Xcode settings]